# query MySQL with PHP but database column has a $

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm building an application around a database(which was built by someone else, so changing it is not an option). I'm querying the database for values which was working fine until I came across a column in the database that has a $ in it.

The code I'm trying to get to work is...

```
$avgprice=mysql_result($result1,$i,"avg$cwt");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to escape `$` sign or use `'` instead of `"`:

```
$avgprice=mysql_result($result1,$i, "avg\$cwt");
// or imho better way to do it:
$avgprice=mysql_result($result1,$i, 'avg$cwt');
```

[PHP strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, variables are parsed within it.

and

> Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"` to prevent PHP from trying to replace the assumed variable.

```
$avgprice=mysql_result($result1,$i,'avg$cwt' );
```

PS: Maybe consider using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of the plain `mysql_X` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes.

```
$avgprice=mysql_result($result1,$i,'avg$cwt');
```

Double quotes interpolate (expand) variables. Single quotes do not. Good practice in PHP is to only use double quotes if you want to interpolate variables in the string. Single quoted strings are processed faster because the interpreter doesn't have to look for variables.